# How can i remove overlaping circles after Hough Transform segmentation

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation, hough-transform

I'm working in image segmentation, testing a lot of different segmentation algorithms, in order to do a comparitive study. At the moment i'm using Hough transform to find circles in the image. The images that i'm using have plenty objects, so when Í count the objects the result is hudge. I think the problem, is the overlaping circle. Do you know how can i maybe remove the overlaping circles to have a result more close to reality?

The code that i'm using is:

```
    clear all, clc;

% Image Reading
I=imread('0001_c3.png');
figure(1), imshow(I);set(1,'Name','Original')
```

[image used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeGqf.jpg)

```
% Gaussian Filter
W = fspecial('gaussian',[10,10]);
J = imfilter(I,W);
figure(2);imshow(J);set(2,'Name','Filtrada média');
X = rgb2gray(J);
figure(3);imshow(X);set(3,'Name','Grey');

% Finding Circular objects -- Houng Transform
[centers, radii, metric] = imfindcircles(X,[10 20], 'Sensitivity',0.92,'Edge',0.03); % [parasites][5 30]

centersStrong = centers(1:60,:); % number of objects
radiiStrong = radii(1:60);
metricStrong = metric(1:60);
viscircles(centersStrong, radiiStrong,'EdgeColor','r');
length(centers)% result=404!
```

Comment: Could you add (or link to) the image `cell.png`?

Comment: @MartinJ.H. I have added the entier code and the image used. thanks a lot in advance for the help :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply loop over the circles and check if others are "close" to them. If so, you ignore them.

```
idx_mask = ones(size(radii));

min_dist = 1; % relative value. Tweak this if slight overlap is OK.
for i = 2:length(radii)
    cur_cent = centers(i, :);
    for j = 1:i-1
        other_cent = centers(j,:);
        x_dist = other_cent(1) - cur_cent(1);
        y_dist = other_cent(2) - cur_cent(2);
        if sqrt(x_dist^2+y_dist^2) < min_dist*(radii(i) + radii(j)) && idx_mask(j) == 1
            idx_mask(i) = 0;
            break
        end
    end
end
%%

idx_mask = logical(idx_mask);
centers_use = centers(idx_mask, :);
radii_use = radii(idx_mask, :);
metric_use = metric(idx_mask, :);

viscircles(centers_use, radii_use,'EdgeColor','b');
```

The picture shows all circles in red, and the filtered circles in blue.

[image: Disting circles]

The `if` clause checks two things:
 - Are the centers of the circles closer than the sum of their radii? 
 - Is the other circle still on the list of considered circles?
If the answer to both questions is yes, then ignore the "current circle".

The way the loop is set up, it will keep circles that are `higher up` (have a lower row index). As is, the circles are already ordered by descending `metric`. In other words, as is this code will keep circles with a higher `metric`.

The code could optimized so that the loops run faster, but I don't think you'll have millions of circles in a single picture. I tried writing it in a way that it's easier to read for humans.